# Prove the equality with power series

Tags: power-series

I have to prove for $|x| < 1$ that
$$
\ln\frac{2(1-\sqrt{1-x})}{x} = \frac 12 \cdot \frac x2 + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac 12 \cdot \frac 34 \cdot \frac 56 \cdot \frac{x^3}{6} + \dots
$$

I tried to use the Taylor series for the left side, but derivatives become too complicated. How can I prove this equality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $u(x)$ to be expanded is such that $u(0)=0$ and $$u'(x)=\frac1{2x}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}-1\right).$$ Assuming one knows that $$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}a_nx^n,$$ with $a_0=1$, this yields $$u(x)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{a_n}{2n}x^n.$$ Can you identify $(a_n)_{n\geqslant1}$? Hint:$$\frac1{\sqrt{1-x}}=(1-x)^\alpha,\qquad \alpha=-\frac12.$$

Comment: How did you get such a derivative?

Comment: Which derivative did you get yourself?

Comment: I have 1/(-2x+2sqrt(1-x)+2)

Comment: 1/(-2x+2sqrt(1-x)+2)=1/(2sqrt(1-x)(sqrt(1-x)+1)) and 1/(sqrt(1-x)+1)=(1-sqrt(1-x))/x hence...